# I cant find the button used to reduce buttons created on a layout in android studio

Tags: android

[![this is the image of my layout on android studio][1]][1]

I am trying to adjust the buttons I created on the layout, but i am not finding the the button to do that on my android studio. the tutorial I am watching called the button "MinWidth", it should be adjusted to 48dp to reduce the buttons.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXVUK.png

Comment: I'm not sure why ``minWidth`` doesn't show up in the design view, but you can add it in the XML by clicking ``Code`` or ``Split`` at the top right (and if you don't know how to edit stuff in there, this is a good time to learn!). But FYI ``minWidth`` won't reduce anything, it'll only ever increase the width to meet that minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try manipulating these parameters of the button :

**android:layout_width
android:layout_height**